# Using Data Driven Page Extents for 2 data frames in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I have an MXD with two data frames. I want to use Data Driven Pages (DDP) to export this to PDF but have the second of the data frames be one extent ahead. I have the following script to export the two frames with the same extent using DDP. I want to have frame2 be one ahead of the DDP page of the master frame.

Any ideas?

```
#set map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#set master data frame - dataframe with DDP already applied
masterFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)

#set second data frame to copy master
frame2 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"New Data Frame")

#for loop to process DDP using number of pages
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
   mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum

   #this sets the extent to be the same but I want frame2 to be one ahead, if that makes sense?
   frame2[0].extent = masterFrame[0].extent
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\pdffolder\"+ str(pageNum) + '.pdf')
```

Comment: I have played around with the DDP Tools, but I am also still learning. I was just wondering if this line: masterFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd) should not also name the "Master Dataframe" something like "masterFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Main")" or perhaps "masterFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]"

Comment: As an aside...could you please edit your question to include the outcomes of running the above script?

Comment: @KeaganAllan what this code does is move two data frames to the same extent and export them based on the DDP. I want them to be different extents, like two DDP, one for each data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works for me.
Let me know if it is what you are looking for. I have put some comments to explain what I did.

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

#set second data frame to copy master

#set map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
#set master data frame - dataframe with DDP already applied
masterFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
Frame2 = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[1]

print  mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount
#for loop to process DDP using number of pages
#I changed your script here to not run to the last page (it would give an error
#if you tried to set Extent 2 to a page that doesn't exist. This gives you an export
# set of P1,P2 ; P2,P3 ; P4,P5 if there are 5 pages.
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount):
    #I have set the Master Dataframe to have the extent of the PageId + 1 (one page ahead)
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum + 1
    #I set Frame 2 to have the same extent as the Master
    Frame2.extent = masterFrame.extent
    #I reset the extent of the Master back to the correct page...then export.
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    print pageNum

    OutF = os.path.join("C:/temp" ,str(pageNum) + ".pdf" )
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, OutF)
```

Comment: Okay. I modified your code to best fit my issues. I had to add Frame2.scale = masterFrame.scale and Frame2.rotation = masterFrame.rotation within the for loop after setting the extent and it looks to have worked. I greatly appreciate your feedback and help on this.